# not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugAnnotationProcessorClasspath

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello I get this error when i try to play app on emulator. I was given project to create my app but i can't contact to developer so i decided to edit it by my self but when i try to play this app on emulator i face this error problem.

```
Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration 
':app:debugAnnotationProcessorClasspath'.
 > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-common:0.8.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1
  > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-common:0.8.
  > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/auto-common/0.8/auto-common-0.8.pom
     > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:3.
        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:3.
           > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/auto-parent/3/auto-parent-3.pom
              > Content is not allowed in prolog.
        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:3.
           > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/auto-parent/3/auto-parent-3.pom
              > Content is not allowed in prolog.
        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:3.
           > Could not parse POM 
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/auto/auto-parent/3/auto-parent-3.pom
              > Content is not allowed in prolog.
  > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-common:0.8.
     > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/auto-common/0.8/auto-common-0.8.pom
          > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:3.
          > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:3.
           > Could not parse POM 
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/auto-parent/3/auto-parent-3.pom
              > Content is not allowed in prolog.
          > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:3.
             > Could not parse POM 
   https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/auto-parent/3/auto-parent-3.pom
              > Content is not allowed in prolog.
          > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:3.
           > Could not parse POM 
   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/auto/auto-parent/3/auto-parent-3.pom
              > Content is not allowed in prolog.
    > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-common:0.8.
     > Could not parse POM 
  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/auto/auto-common/0.8/auto-common-0.8.pom
         > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:3.
           > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:3.
           > Could not parse POM 
  https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/auto-parent/3/auto-parent-3.pom
              > Content is not allowed in prolog.
          > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:3.
           > Could not parse POM 
   https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/auto-parent/3/auto-parent-3.pom
              > Content is not allowed in prolog.
        > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:3.
           > Could not parse POM 
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/auto/auto-parent/3/auto-parent-3.pom
              > Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Comment: Clean/Re-build it may work

Comment: not working error still there!

Comment: Check the proxy connection. You should have open internet to build it again

Comment: yes i have open internet connection